# ARKit/SceneKit Shadow Issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I'm working on an ARKit app for iPhone and iPad and I'm having some troubles getting the shadows to work in the live view from the camera. My scene (`ShadowTest.scn`) looks like the following:

[image: Scene Graph]

I have unchecked `Red`, `Green`, `Blue`, and `Alpha` for the `Write to Color` property on the material for the plane as well as set the visibility to `Cull back`.

For the directional light, `Enable Shadows` is selected and the mode is set to `Deferred`.

In the scene file itself, everything looks good. The shadow is visible and the plane is not.

My issue is when I go to add it to my scene view. This is how I'm adding it to my scene:

```swift
func addTestBox(at position: SCNVector3, rotation: SCNVector4) {
    guard let scene = SCNScene(named: "Assets.scnassets/ShadowTest.scn") else {
        return
    }

    let node = SCNNode()

    scene.rootNode.childNodes.forEach(node.addChildNode(_:))

    node.position = position
    node.rotation = rotation

    updateQueue.async { [weak self] in
        self?.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    }
}
```

When the nodes are added to my scene, the shadow is not visible at all.

[image: AR View with no Shadow]

The lighting appears to be working because it is lit as it should be.

Am I missing some very obvious setting on the light/plane/cube/scene view that is needed to make the shadows show up?

Thank you in advanced for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in code. Try this for the light:

```
func directionalLight() -> SCNLight {
    
    let light                           = SCNLight()
    light.type                          = .directional
    light.castsShadow                   = true
    light.color                         = UIColor.white
    light.shadowColor                   = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.75)
    light.shadowMode                    = .deferred
    light.shadowRadius                  = 2.0
    light.shadowCascadeCount            = 3
    light.shadowCascadeSplittingFactor  = 0.09
    light.shadowBias                    = 0.1
    light.shadowSampleCount             = 8 // (the smaller the value, the better the performance)
    light.categoryBitMask               = -1 // Shine on Everything

    return light
    
}
```

and this for the Material:

```
func shadowMaterialStandard() -> SCNMaterial {
    
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    
    
    material.diffuse.contents       = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    material.lightingModel          = .physicallyBased
    material.colorBufferWriteMask   = SCNColorMask(rawValue: 0)
    material.isLitPerPixel          = false
    material.isDoubleSided          = true
    
    
    return material
}
```

and this for the SCNPlane (the Shadow Plane):

```
func setupShadowPlane() {
    
    let objectShape = SCNPlane(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
    objectShape.heightSegmentCount = 1
    objectShape.widthSegmentCount = 1
    
    let objectNode = SCNNode(geometry: objectShape)
    objectNode.renderingOrder = -10 // for Shadow Material Standard
    objectNode.position = initialStartPosition
    objectNode.geometry?.firstMaterial = shadowMaterialStandard()
    objectNode.castsShadow = false // Important
    objectNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(-90.degreesToRadians, 0.0, 0.0)
    objectNode.name = "floor"
    objectNode.physicsBody = Physics.floorPhysicsBody(shape: objectShape)
    
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(objectNode)
    
}
```